# How to i can give refference of of xcode project in another xcode project?

Tags: xcode, reference, project

I have develop xcode project and i want to use this project as one module of another project so how i can give old project reference in new project?

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the first project into the window of the second project and it will automatically be added as a sub-project. You can then set up target dependencies as needed so that the sub-project will automatically get built first when needed.